# Best strategy for C(n,2) keys in redis

Tags: memcached, redis

I'm working on a project that I'm going to explain to you.

I have N(10000 < N < 100000) objects, that each of them have a relationship with each others which can be represented as an integer. So I need to store the C(N,2) relationships in a database and be able to retrieve any of them randomly as quick as possible.

The relationships are calculated by algorithms. So with different algorithms, we have different set of relationships. Algorithms are changing, but active algorithms would be limited to less than 3.

I wish to keep as much relationships in memory as possible, or in disk if random retrieval of them is faster than recalculation.

I found redis the best thing to try, but we have 2 billion objects so I wish to reduce memory usage as much as possible.

Each object and each algorithm is represented by an UUID.

My question is, what is the best strategy? Should I use the redis HashMap and how? Should I use the redis vm? How to design the keys(since it is too long if simply concat the uuids)?

Comment: redis VM is deprecated, you should not use it

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot store all your data in main memory, and need to use the disk, then Redis is not the correct choice. The VM code was deprecated with Redis 2.4, and removed in Redis 2.6.

Also it is not especially efficient to store relationships between UUIDs, because UUIDs cannot be encoded in a single 64 bits integer. Redis space optimizations for sets rely on the fact object references are 64 bits integers (and typically, relationships are materialized by sets with Redis).

I think you would be better served by a graph database such as Neo4J or OrientDB whose purpose is to store this kind of relationships.